# jQuery animate()-call is very slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, animation, jquery-animate

I am using jQuery for my single page web application and am now in the need of animating a single DIV's height from a fixed value to another fixed value (from ~50px to 75px).

I know experience terrible performance trouble, surprisingly not regarding the animation itself but the actual call of the animate()-method.

```
window.time = {};
time.start = new Date().getTime();

$('div').animate({height: '25px'}, 500);

time.end = new Date().getTime();
```

Running this snippet, the animation of ALL DIV's on the page is again fluent, but

```
time.end - time.start = 190
```

So the initialization of the animation needs about 190ms

Of course, this response time is unaccaptable.

Did some of you ever experienced such an issue and has an idea/solution?

Thanks in advance!

Leo

Answer (score 0):

I've never had the performance of such calls be particularly bad, but it will scale with the number of divs you're animating obviously, maybe that's your problem.

If you just want to get on with other things that aren't dependent on the animation, run it separately by using a `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 0)`, complete whatever you're doing and it'll be executed when you return from the function you're in.

Answer (score 0):

For every div will be done some work (set start and end values, set intervals, calculate step increments etc). So duration depends on count of divs, it is linearly proportional to it, and I don't see some legal way to improve it using jquery.